# How to test Post Request in Postman for a DTO that contains file type

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

Sorry, but I wanted to confirm if there was a way to do this without having to serialize to JSON, which is what I kept on reading online.

The problem that I am having is that I want to test with Postman my email service which has a Email dto of

> { 
> String toEmail 
> String subjectLine 
> String content 
> List<File> attachments (Text files can be used for test if that helps)
>
> }

Previously, before adding the list of files, I could use Postman to test with raw under the **body tab of postman** and sending in a json. However, I don't think I can add an object with that same method. When trying out form-data though, I am getting that **the request entity is in a format not supported**.

Currently, my service is only taking in a EmailDto as its resource.

Does anyone have suggestions or thoughts?